# Google App Engine failed to compile jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine

I already set it to jdk instead of jre 
java version used for compile is 1.7
it work on tomcat server but I need to get working on local app engine 
Eclipse is used with the GAE plugin
The jsp file currently only has the word hello for testing

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /getAllCourses. Reason:

    Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
    at com.example.mmu.getAllCourses.doGet(getAllCourses.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working . U need to download the 1.7 jdk from oracle . So if you have the 1.8 and set it to 1.7 in the eclipse compiler this wont work. you need the 1.7 version and add that to the build path